# Read large number of CSV files from S3 bucket

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to read large number of csv files from S3 bucket. CSV files are in different partitions. I am using Boto3 to list all the paths to csv. Then iterating on the list using for loop to read csv files into spark dataframe. I need a better optimized way to reading huge amount of files from S3 paths, as looping is a linear approach which takes a lot of time to finish.
Listing all the objects:

`self.all_objects = [file_path['Key'] for resp_content in self.s3.get_paginator("list_objects_v2").paginate(Bucket='bucketName') for file_path in resp_content['Contents']]`

Reading each CSV files in loop:

`csv_df = self.spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(s3_path)`

Also I want to merge all the dataframe together to create one parquet file.

Thanks in advance if someone has a good solution to it please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Read csv files with many folders (Spark + Scala):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{IntegerType, StringType, StructField, StructType}

val sourcesFolders = List("/home/mykolavasyliv/tmp/source1/", "/home/mykolavasyliv/tmp/source2/", "/home/mykolavasyliv/tmp/source3/")

//  :~/tmp$ tree
//    .
//  ├── source1
//  │   └── person-data-1.csv
//  ├── source2
//  │   └── person-data-2.csv
//  └── source3
//      └── person-data-3.csv

//  person-data-1.csv:
//  source-1-1,Mykola ,23,100
//  source-1-2,Jon,34,76
//  source-1-3,Marry,25,123

//  person-data-2.csv
//  source-2-1,Mykola ,23,100
//  source-2-2,Jon,34,76
//  source-2-3,Marry,25,123

//  person-data-3.csv
//  source-3-1,Mykola ,23,100
//  source-3-2,Jon,34,76
//  source-3-3,Marry,25,123




// Read csv files not use schema

val sourceDF = spark.read.csv(sourcesFolders:_*)

sourceDF.show(false)
//  +----------+-------+---+---+
//  |_c0       |_c1    |_c2|_c3|
//  +----------+-------+---+---+
//  |source-1-1|Mykola |23 |100|
//  |source-1-2|Jon    |34 |76 |
//  |source-1-3|Marry  |25 |123|
//  |source-2-1|Mykola |23 |100|
//  |source-2-2|Jon    |34 |76 |
//  |source-2-3|Marry  |25 |123|
//  |source-3-1|Mykola |23 |100|
//  |source-3-2|Jon    |34 |76 |
//  |source-3-3|Marry  |25 |123|
//  +----------+-------+---+---+



// Read csv files use schema

val schema = StructType(
  List(
    StructField("id", StringType, true),
    StructField("name", StringType, true),
    StructField("age", IntegerType, true),
    StructField("NotKnow", IntegerType, true)
  )
)

val source2DF = spark.read.schema(schema).csv(sourcesFolders:_*)

source2DF.show(false)
//  +----------+-------+---+-------+
//  |id        |name   |age|NotKnow|
//  +----------+-------+---+-------+
//  |source-1-1|Mykola |23 |100    |
//  |source-1-2|Jon    |34 |76     |
//  |source-1-3|Marry  |25 |123    |
//  |source-2-1|Mykola |23 |100    |
//  |source-2-2|Jon    |34 |76     |
//  |source-2-3|Marry  |25 |123    |
//  |source-3-1|Mykola |23 |100    |
//  |source-3-2|Jon    |34 |76     |
//  |source-3-3|Marry  |25 |123    |
//  +----------+-------+---+-------+
```

Comment: While code-only answers might answer the question, you could significantly improve the quality of your answer by providing context for your code, a reason for why this code works, and some references to documentation for further reading.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Sorry. Thank you. Fixed.